# SoundCloud Custom Player Not Playing Until Paused and Resumed on Mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, soundmanager2, mobile-browser

There seems to be an issue with the SoundCloud SDK when used on any mobile browsers. The track doesn't play until I pause and then resume.

```
SC.stream(trackInfo.url,function(sound){
    sound.play();
});
```

Is this a known issue/behavior? I first thought it's an issue with Android, but I got the same behavior when tested on an iPhone.

---

**EDITED**

I thought this might be an async loading issue, but even if I don't call sound.play() right away and have it triggered by user clicking play, it still doesn't work. I have to call play > pause > resume. The good news is that once user take these actions, all subsequent tracks in the custom playlist (non-SoundCloud) can continuously play without any user having to take any actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems like the issue is the async loading after more testing. User has to explicitly click play after it's loaded. I got a little thrown off before because there was an unrelated issue that was causing the pause/resume effect. Once user has triggered the action, it's able to play all tracks without any further action from user.